# Keyword "Click Element" doesn't always work correct

Tags: selenium-rc, robotframework

I'm facing problem, that keyword "Click Element" doesn't always work correct.

For example, I want to go to the link on the web-site.

xpath for the Link is the:

```
${xpathIMButton}                xpath=//a/span[contains(text(),"${exprIM}")]
${exprIM}                       Infrastructure Management
```

To click on the Link with Mouse Over I use following:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element            ${xpathIMButton}
Mouse Over                                  ${xpathIMButton}
Click Element                               ${xpathIMButton}    don't wait
```

That's pretty simple, but what I see on the Logs is confusing:

[image: Logs]

The screenshot from HTML-source of the button:

[image: html-code for button]

So, the Robot finds the link (Wait Until Page Contains Element and Mouse Over) are OK, but the Click Element fails. On the screenshot I can see, that the button actually exists. So what is the problem? Why I get those confusing error?

I'm using:
RFW 2.7.5
SeleniumLibrary 2.8.1
Firefox 12

Comment: Is the page using frames? I've seen similar problems when there are multiple frames on the page. Try using keyword [Select Frame](http://rtomac.github.com/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Select%20Frame) prior to clicking the element.

Comment: No, there is no frames on the page. The problem with frames is by the way popular too.

Comment: Can you post the HTML source code of the page? Preferably to http://jsfiddle.net/ or similar service.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the entire source code, but this should be enough:
http://gyazo.com/464a0232aa65d622754c4c33c99858f3.png

Comment: I am having this same issue as well. I cannot get Selenium2Library to recognize any elements by their link text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element            ${xpathIMButton}
Mouse Over                                  ${xpathIMButton}
Click Element                               ${xpathIMButton}    don't wait
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm checking this on a small screen. Haven't seen you are already passing an argument to the Click Element keyword. Unfortunately I don't have any other ideas how to solve this and I don't have the correct environment ready to experiment at the moment. I would yet try to play around with the `don't wait` part, trying things like `dont_wait` or `dont_wait=1` to see if you get any different output. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
The problem is, that Robot doesn't see the button at all. If there were the problem with 'dont wait' argument, I would become error messages like 'Timed out after 20.000ms'. But I get message about not finding an element, which is something else.

Comment: I installed SeleniumLibrary 2.9.1 but could not reproduce the error. `Click Element` passes if I provide an extra attribute (e.g. `don't wait`) and fails if no argument is provided. Maybe it's worth a shot to upgrade to the latest version of SeleniumLibrary and Selenium Server. Also, I couldn't reproduce this with Selenium2Library.

Answer (score 0):

`Click Element` started to fail for me when I upgraded to Selenium 2.35, *SeleniumLibrary 2.9.1* and Selenium2Library 1.2. My browser was Firefox 22. The `Click Element` was pressing a Save button. The same exact code worked 2 times and the third time said it worked but the confirm page never showed up. I solved my issue by putting a `Focus` keyword before my `Click Element`

```
Focus ${saveRule}

Click Element ${saveRule}
```

Now the code works the three times it is called. Hope this helps.

Comment: "Focus" means that element will be focused and I didn't need that. I had to Click Element with Mouse Over, but without being focused.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a little late to provide an answer, but I had exactly this problem. What I did was to provide a bit waiting time for the page to fully load, then my button was successfully found.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Mouse Over could cause the issue. The Mouse Over could cause the element to be hidden in DOM.

But this was 6 years ago with Selenium 1 Library. Now, we are using Selenium2Library in ROBOT Framework, so if you give a try or already done it, just let us know.

Comment: As you mentioned it, it was 6 years ago. I'm doing completely different things for now.